# function that produces a two dimensional list from files containing numbers

Tags: python

Write a function table() that takes a parameter a string representing a file name and a number n.  The function should open and read the contents of the corresponding file.  The file will contain one line with exactly n*n numbers separated by blank spaces.  The function table() should create and return an n x n two-dimensional list containing the n*n numbers as follows: The first row of the table will contain the first n numbers, the second row will contain the next n numbers, and so on until the nth row.  The following shows what table() should display when run on the files data1.txt and data2.txt.

> > > table('data1.txt', 3)

[['3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10', '11']]

> > > table('data2.txt', 4)

[['3', '4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9', '10'], ['11', '12', '13', '14'], ['15', '16', '17', '18']]

Clearly a homework question, so **NO answers**, just pointers to help me get started. I have no clue where to start.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Or are you looking for pseudocode?

Comment: Python! Sorry forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume when you say "no answers", you mean no code.

- Open the file.
- Read the command line argument (`n`).
- Create a list (`x`).
- Enter a loop, executed `n` times.

  - Read n entries from the file into another list (`y`) (probably a sub-loop).
  - Add list `y` to list `x`.

Breaking things into individual small goals like that often makes the task easier.

Comment: What do you mean in the second bullet?

Comment: Parameter string... first being the filename, second part being "n"

Answer (score 1):

First, this page shows some ways of [reading a file.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)  When you read a line of a file, you are going to get back a string.  Look into [methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) that will make it easy to break up that string into n parts. Finally, you will want to read about how to operate on lists, [this tutorial will help.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers: Create an n*n size matrix, use a two nested for loops from `0` to `n-1` and read each element sequentially into `[i][j]` where `i` is the iterator in the outer loop and `j` the one in the inner loop.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by n*n array? I'm pretty new to python, and don't really understand the lingo.

Comment: @97834657647563: I did not see this was a Python question.

Comment: Yeah, the term "array" doesn't occur much in python, you should really be looking at lists.